# Split a string to populate two DIVs

Tags: php, split

Please guys, Am building a football betting website and the data feed company is giving me home and away team in a single column seperated by - sign.
I have tried to ponder on it but gets more confused
this is what I have:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM participant_template";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $teams = $row['teams'];
        // The output of $teams looks like this: Manchester - Chelsea
        $home_team = "Please help me out";
        $away_team = "Please help me out";
    }
}
```

How do I separate them to home team and away team.

Comment: This looks like you are using php

Answer (score 1):

Try that. This solution is expecting teams will always separated by '-'

```
// The output of $teams looks like this: Manchester - Chelsea
$teamsArr = explode("-",$teams);
$home_team = trim($teamsArr[0]);
$away_team = trim($teamsArr[1]);
```

Again you should tag this question as PHP, not sql.

Comment: I don't know PHP enough to know so I am asking more for me:  Will that create a trailing space on the first team name and a leading space on the second team name?  Requiring the PHP equivalent of trim()?

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply I really appreciate your effot. God bless you

Comment: Yes it will obviously needed to be trimmed. editing ans.

Comment: @Kapil: use `explode(" - ", $teams);` for the whitespaces... or use `trim()`

Comment: @AlexRuhl We can only if there is guaranty that there always will be a space before and after '-'. However it is difficult to give such guaranty in case of spaces, human errors always possible. So I still think using trim later is better option. Always keep your programs secure from human errors.

Comment: @Kapil Sharma - That is what I was guessing.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. My script is now working perfectly to an extent where I can carry on with it. I really appreciate all your efforts. You saved me this night's headache